# No me funciona el 'multipart-formdata'

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, quasar

colegas. En serio necesito ayuda: No importa qué intente, pero lo enviado con `new FormData()` siempre lo recibo como `NULL`. Así lo envío:

```javascript
<template>
    <q-form @submit.prevent="signupUser">
        <q-card-section>
            <div class="row q-my-md">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 q-px-sm">
                    <q-select outlined v-model="documentType" label="Tipo de documento" :options="validStore.documentTypes"></q-select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 q-px-sm">
                    <q-input outlined v-model="documentUser" label="Número de documento"></q-input>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row q-my-md">
                <div class="col-12 q-px-sm">
                    <q-file outlined v-model="file" ref="pdf" accept="application/pdf" label="Comprobante documento" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row q-my-md">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 q-px-sm">
                    <q-input outlined v-model="name" label="Nombre(s) completo(s)"></q-input>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 q-px-sm">
                    <q-input outlined v-model="lastName" label="Apellido(s) completo(s)"></q-input>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row q-my-md">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 q-px-sm">
                    <q-input outlined v-model="email" label="Correo electrónico"></q-input>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 q-px-sm">
                    <q-input outlined v-model="password" label="Contraseña"></q-input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </q-card-section>

        <q-card-actions vertical>
            <q-btn type="submit" color="positive" label="registrarme" icon="person_add" class="long-btn"></q-btn>
        </q-card-actions>
    </q-form>
</template>

<script setup>
    // Importar internos
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    import api from '../assets/scripts/plugins/axios.js'

    // Importar stores
    import { useValidStore } from '../assets/scripts/stores/ValidStore.js'

    // Variables de configuración
    const validStore = useValidStore()

    // Variables del componente
    const documentType = ref(null)
    const documentUser = ref(null)
    const file = ref(null)
    const name = ref(null)
    const lastName = ref(null)
    const email = ref(null)
    const password = ref(null)

    // Funciones
    const signupUser = () => {
        console.clear()

        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('documentType', documentType.value)
        formData.append('documentUser', documentUser.value)
        formData.append('file', file.value)
        formData.append('name', name.value)
        formData.append('lastName', lastName.value)
        formData.append('email', email.value)
        formData.append('password', password.value)

        api.put('/new/user', formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
</script>
```

Así lo recibo:

```php
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");

date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");

require_once(__DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php");

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

// Router
use Api\Http\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

// Importar controladores.
use Api\Controllers\UbicationsController;
use Api\Controllers\DepartmentsController;
use Api\Controllers\UsersController;
use Api\Controllers\Prueba;

use Api\Http\Middlewares\AuthMiddleware;

//crear un objeto request a partir de las variables globales del servidor
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

Router::init();

Router::group(['prefix' => '/api/v3'], function() {
    //Router::filter('CleanInputMiddleware', [new \Api\Http\Middlewares\CleanInputMiddleware(Request::createFromGlobals()), 'handle']);

    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    $clear = new \Api\Http\Middlewares\CleanInputMiddleware($request);
    $clear->handle();

    // Ruta que recibe los datos de un usuario que desea registrarse
    Router::put('/new/user', function() {
        $user = new UsersController();
        var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)); // Me muestra NULL
        //print_r($user->createUser());
    });
});

//ejecutar el despachador y obtener la respuesta
Router::dispatch($request);
```

Y ese es el middleware que define mi objeto `$this->request`:

```php
<?php

namespace Api\Http\Middlewares;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class CleanInputMiddleware {

    public $request;
    public $content;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        // Obtener el objeto Request
        $this->request = $request;

        // Obtener el contenido del request
        $this->content = $request->getContent();

        if (strpos($this->request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'multipart/form-data') !== false) {
            $this->formData();
        }
    }

    public function handle() {
        // Verificar si el contenido es un JSON válido
        if(json_decode($this->content) === null){
            // El contenido no es un JSON válido, no hacer nada
            return;
        }

        // Eliminar código PHP
        $this->content = preg_replace('/<\?(.*)\?>/', '', $this->content);

        // Eliminar la etiqueta <script>
        $this->content = preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $this->content);

        // Eliminar sentencias SQL
        $this->content = preg_replace('/[\s(;)(\/\*)(--)(\s)]*(SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|DROP|TRUNCATE|ALTER|GRANT|REVOKE|COMMIT|ROLLBACK|CREATE|USE|SHOW|DESCRIBE|EXPLAIN)[\s\S]*[;]*/i', '', $this->content);

        // Asignar el contenido limpio al request
        $this->request->request->replace(json_decode($this->content, true));

        // Crear una sesión con los datos limpios
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();
        $session->clear();
        $session->set('clean_request_data', json_decode($this->content, true));
    }

    private function formData() {
        $boundary = substr($this->content, 0, strpos($this->content, "\r\n"));
        $parts = array_slice(explode($boundary, $this->content), 1);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if ($part == "--\r\n") continue;

            $part = ltrim($part, "\r\n");
            list($rawHeaders, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $part, 2);
            $rawHeaders = explode("\r\n", $rawHeaders);
            $headers = array();
            foreach ($rawHeaders as $header) {
                list($name, $value) = explode(':', $header);
                $headers[strtolower($name)] = ltrim($value, ' ');
            }

            if (isset($headers['content-disposition'])) {
                $filename = null;
                $tmp_name = null;
                preg_match(
                    '/^form-data; *name="([^"]+)"(; *filename="([^"]+)")?/',
                    $headers['content-disposition'],
                    $matches
                );
                list(, $name) = $matches;
                if (isset($matches[3])) {
                    $filename = $matches[3];
                    $tmp_name =  $body;
                    $data[$name] = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile($tmp_name, $filename);
                } else {
                    $data[$name] = $body;
                }
            }
        }

        $this->request->request->replace($data);
    }

}
```

> Estoy usando Quasar (^1.15.9), Vue (^3.2.45), Axios (^1.2.3), PHRoute (^2.2) y http-foundation (^6.2).

> Usar `var_dump($_FILES)` me devuelve un array vacío, ya sea dentro o fuera de las rutas.

Comment: en que punto de tu codigo has validado si recibes algo en mediante put?

Comment: Las rutas son correctas, tengo unas que son sólo para testear, pero no las puse aquí para no ocupar espacio. Pero estoy empezando a creer que el problema es cómo estoy enviando el archivo: Creé un nuevo proyecto sólo con un `index.php` y aún así, `$_FILES` sigue vacío.

Comment: entonces debes hacer primero debug sobre el formdata antes de enviarlo.

Comment: El formData me devuelve "File {__key: '16578318652632022(planes).pdf8634703', name: '2022(planes).pdf', lastModified: 1657831865263, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 14 2022 15:51:05 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia), webkitRelativePath: '', …}", pero no lo recibe.

Comment: eso que agregaste no dice nada ... tienes que hacer el debug y validar... prueba investigando como validar que el archivo tenga la extencion correcta dentro de un formdata etc ...

Comment: Pues es que eso es lo único que me arroja y sólo está para PDF, así que no sé qué otras validaciones debería hacer.

Comment: validar que el achivo fue agregado al formdata???

Comment: Sí, está dentro del formData, es el archivo que yo seleccioné, la extensión, el peso, todo; o sea, todo está bien, excepto en la parte en el que se envía  y no entiendo porqué de un lado sí funciona, pero en el otro es vacío.

Comment: mientras no muestres que has intentado ... y exactamente donde ocurre el error poco podemos hacer ... esto no se trata de adivinar ...

Comment: No sé si acaso me falta algún header, o estoy usando el `FormData()` mal, o algo así. También me gustaría aclarar que por ejemplo, si al `formData` le agrego los otros campos, igualmente no los puedo ver ni con `$_GET`, ni `$_POST`, ni mucho menos con `$_FILES`, lo que me hace sospechar que en serio es el JavaScript, o Axios.

Comment: Al usar `console.log(formData.get('file')) // File {__key: '1655391430474Consiliación.pdf130316', name: 'Consiliación.pdf', lastModified: 1655391430474, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 16 2022 09:57:10 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia), webkitRelativePath: '', …}` me arroja lo que dice en el comentario; o sea, sí está dentro de mi `formdata`

Comment: valida algo ... cual es el contenido de file.value en javascript

Comment: Usar `console.log(file.value)` me arroja exactamente lo mismo, sin ningún cambio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En javascript, los archivos no se encuentran en la propiedad `value`, este parte del codigo esta incorrecta:

```
formData.append('file', file.value)
```

la forma correcta de agregar un archivo a un objeto `new FormData();` es la siguiente:

```javascript
let formData = new FormData();
let fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
let file = fileInput.files[0];
formData.append("file_field", file);
```

Si necesita meter varios archivos seria de la siguiente forma:

```javascript
let formData = new FormData();
let fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
let files = fileInput.files;

for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    formData.append("file_field_"+i, files[i]);
}
```

Enviar al Backend los datos con `axios` (Como veras aqui hay otro cambio, estoy usando `post` en lugar de `put`), no necesitas declarar el `headers` del tipo `Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` ya que el metodo post lo hace por defecto:

```javascript
axios.post('/new/user', formData)
    .then(function (response) {
        // manejar la respuesta del servidor
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // manejar el error
    });
```

Para recibir en PHP los archivos enviados mediante los anteriores ejemplo deberias implementar la variable super global `$_FILES` de la siguiente forma:

```php
$file = $_FILES["file_field"];
//o
$file_0 = $_FILES["file_field_0"];
$file_1 = $_FILES["file_field_1"];
```

debes adaptar este codigo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero infortunadamente, sigue sin funcionar. Este es mi código:

```javascript
 const sendFile = () => {

  let fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type='file']")

  console.log(fileInput) // <input tabindex="-1" type="file" title="" accept="application/pdf" id="f_e816e83e-4be9-4bd3-8896-96464421e286" class="q-field__input fit absolute-full cursor-pointer">

  console.log(fileInput.files) // FileList {length: 0}

  console.log(fileInput.files[0]) // undefined
 }
```

Comment: En los comentarios, se ve el valor devuelto

Comment: verifica cambiando a post ... el metodo de axios y quitando el header, mira mi ejemplo...

Comment: todo lo que estas  viendo lo he probado y va 100%... puedes hacerlo sin tu framework ... con un simple archivo index.php y metiendole las librerias ...

Comment: estoy casi seguro que tu error es el poco de header que tiene tu archivo php en donde recibes los datos ... tienes un `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");` y otro poco de codigo que no se entiende ... yo tu haria una pruena con un archivo limpio... y el codigo minimo necesario... si te funciona entonces de hay partes agregando cosas ...

Comment: Pues sí me funcionó lo que hiciste y lo de los header no tenían nada que ver. Después de implementar tu solución (con algunos cambios), lo cambié a POST y listo.

Comment: fue lo primero que te dice ... cambia put por post ...